# How can I use powershell to check if a mapped drive is open / connected?

Tags: powershell, network-share, login-script

I am writing a login script which unmaps and remaps some drives.

The powershell calls a small batch file for the actual unmapping, as Powershell seems a bit flaky at reliably mapping the drives.

The code I am using is:

```
    $arrDrives = "m:","n:","o:","p:","q:","r:","s:","u:","v:","x:","y:"
    foreach ($drive in $arrDrives) { 
        if (test-path $drive) {
            UpdateSubHeading ("Removing drive " + $drive)
            c:\bin\removeDrive.bat $drive } 
    }
```

And the batch file it calls is just:

```
if exist %1 net use %1 /del
```

This all works fine, unless there is an open connection to the drive it is trying to unmap. If the user has a file open, then it hangs.

Is there a way I can check if there are any connections open to the mapped drive before I try and unmap it, and skip unmapping it if there are?

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script is probably waiting for permission to delete the connection

e.g.

```
M:\>net use m: /delete
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searched pending on the connection to m:.

Is it OK to continue disconnection and force them closed (Y/N) [N]:
```

You need to provide the permission on the command line

e.g

```
M:\>net use m: /delete /yes
There are open files and/or incomplete directory searched pending on the connection to m:.

m: was deleted successfully
```

or in your case

```
if exist %1 net use %1 /del /yes
```